# QR Decomp: Better to Round 'Identically Zero' Value to Zero?

Tags: matrix, numerical-methods, zero, floating-point-precision

I could not find anything on the subject here. I might be searching the wrong terms. My question is this:

"Suppose you're performing a QR decomposition of an mxn matrix, X, using Householder reflections in order to solve the linear equation Xb = y. At each iteration, R = Qi*Qi-1*...Q1*X, progressing toward an upper triangular matrix. If finite precision round-off causes the values of R that should, by definition, be identically zero to be some non-zero value on the order of machine epsilon, is it better to round that value to zero or leave it be?"

Many thanks.

Comment: That depends entirely on what “some matrix algebra” is, where your data came from, and what you intend to do with the result.  As asked, it is impossible to answer this question.  Rigorous numerical analysis rarely admits “one size fits all” answers.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I hope it's clear enough to provide a useful answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific case of QR decomposition, you usually don’t even bother computing the matrix entries that you know are going to be zeroed out by a Householder reflection; you simply treat them as zero from that point on (in fact, you generally don’t even bother storing the zeros, and instead use that space to store the reflection itself).

Comment: +1 Besides standing well on its own, this answer also fills in the gap in mine.  @StephenCanon is right: it is best not even to store the almost-zeros.

Answer (score 2):

This fine question is the best I have seen in a week on StackOverflow.

Answer:  Round it!  A major point of the QR decomposition is precisely that the factors in question be well-conditioned, that there be no tiny/huge eigenvalues in Q.  When there are no tiny/huge eigenvalues, rounding doesn't hurt.

What point would there be in the QR if it did not let you round your almost-zeros off to zero?

Comment: Both useful answers. Yours made me think.